# How can I select components wrapped in ForwardRef with Material UI v4?

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, e2e-testing, testcafe

Since version 4 material ui started wrapping all their components with `forwardRef`. In my testcafe tests I was relying on the "testcafe-react-selectors" library to select components based on their name. So e.g.

```
export namespace TimeSlotListPage {
  export const TimeSlotList = ReactSelector('TimeSlotList');
  export const TimeSlotListItem: Selector = ReactSelector('ListItem');
}
```

Now with version 4 the document appears as `ForwardRef(List)` in the react- dev-tools, but selecting for this with `ReactSelector('ForwardRef(List)')` does not work and neither does `ReactSelector('MergeListContext')`. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

As we didn't face any issues with the unreleased Material UI v4 framework, we would need to research it thoroughly.

I would appreciate it if you prepare a simple project that demonstrates the issue and create a separate bug report in the TestCafe repository using the following [form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md).